# Android How can i change the layout orientation inflated into ViewPager without calling onCreate?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator, fragmentpageradapter

i am using a viewpager which loads some layouts and is doing something on sliding. I want to be able when the activity is changing the orientation, the pager changes the layout to specific orientation without loading the data again. Is this possible ??

I know that in order to avoid calling onCreate method over and over again you have to specify in your manifest the line bellow and then use onConfigurationChanged:

android:configChanges="orientation"

But doing this the layout will not load the right layout according to orientation(so if is landscape load the landscape layout), instead it keeps the loaded layout and resize it.

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
        case Constants.LAYOUT_FEEDBACK:
            resId = R.layout.activity_feedback; 
            view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
            ((ViewPager)collection).addView(view, 0);

            btnSend = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
            etFeedback = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etFeedback);
            etEmail = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etMail);

            sendFeedback(btnSend);

            break;
        case Constants.LAYOUT_HOME:
            resId = R.layout.activity_home;

            view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

            ((ViewPager)collection).addView(view, 0);

            btnCamera = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
            btnPoo = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btnPoo);
            imgPopular = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnPopular);
            imgRecent = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnRecent);
            imgNearby = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnNearby);

            btnEdit = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
            btnFeedback = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btnFeedback);

            incSearch = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.include_search, null);
            incNoInternet = view.findViewById(R.id.include_no_internet);
            incNoInternet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            btnCancel = (Button)incSearch.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
            imgX = (ImageView)incSearch.findViewById(R.id.imgX);
            etKeywords = (EditText)incSearch.findViewById(R.id.etText);

            btnRetry = (Button)incNoInternet.findViewById(R.id.btnTryAgain);

            pooAdapter = new PooAdapter(poos);
            lvPoo = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lvPoo);
            lvPoo.addHeaderView(incSearch);
            lvPoo.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            lvPoo.setAdapter(pooAdapter);
```

Comment: Did you find out how to inflate for specific orientation?